# NDSolveValue. x cannot be used as a variable

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Im trying to solve an electrocinetic problem that is supposed to be very easy. I only need a region and some DirichletCondition, adn then solve the Lagrange equation. Here you've got the program.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Clear[Rint, Rext, vint, vext, x, y, u, uif, e0, o1, o2, o]
Rint = 2;
Rext = 4;
vint = 1;
vext = 0;

o1 = Disk[{0, 0}, Rext];
o2 = RegionDifference[o1, Disk[{0, 0}, Rint]];
o = RegionDifference[o2, Rectangle[{-Rext, -Rext}, {Rext, 0}]];

CC = {
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == vext, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == Rext],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == vint, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == Rint]
   };

uif = NDSolveValue[{Lagrangian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, CC}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Epsilon] o, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}}];
```

Then, this message appears:

```
NDSolveValue::dsvar: x \[Epsilon] BooleanRegion[#1&&!#2&&!#3&,{Disk[{0,0},4],Disk[{0,0},2],Rectangle[{-4,-4},{4,0}]}] cannot be used as a variable.
```

I can't undestand why this happens, as I have a model program very similar to this one as an example.

Comment: The syntax for region membership is `{x, y} \[Element] o`, not `\[Epsilon]`.  (It's not complaining about `x` but about the whole expression.)

Comment: What is: `Lagrangian` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Oh, I forgot I changed that to `Laplacian`. If it's `Lagrangian`, then Sergio forgot (to include) the definition.  But the syntax error seems the major problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 that was the problem ^^ thank you very much! how do a say that your answer worked? i mean how to accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for region membership is `{x, y} \[Element] o`, not `\[Epsilon]`, which look very similar:

```
{x, y} \[Element] o
{x, y} \[Epsilon] o
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unless `\[Epsilon]` has a definition, it will show up blue instead of black. (The error message is not complaining about x but about the whole expression.)